# Efficient way to get number of nodes / relations in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, profiling, cypher

**TLDR**

Query `MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)` scans all nodes, can I do it in O(1)?

**Full question**

I added million nodes to graph and run query to count them

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)
```

Which results in all nodes scan and takes 2 seconds:

[image]

Adding index on label and property does not change situation

```
Indexes
  ON :USER(userId)     ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
Constraints
  ON (user:USER) ASSERT user.userId IS UNIQUE
```

So the next query also runs in 2 seconds

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n: USER) RETURN count(n)
```

[image]

Counting relations with queries like

```
MATCH ()-[r]->() return count(r)
MATCH ()-[r:relation_type]->() return count(r)
```

Also results in similar plan with 5 seconds execution time (3M relations)

Is there better syntax to query for count of nodes / relations which would result in < O(n)? Or should we never count all nodes / relations? I would like to know why indexes do not cover these queries and what is blocking from making these queries fast.

Comment: Version 3.0.1 is used store counters: `NodeCountFromCountStore` and `RelationshipCountFromCountStore`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. And what for older versions?

Comment: see http://jexp.github.io/blog/html/fast-node-by-label-counts-in-neo4j.html